# Flink custom metrics are not shown in Datadog

Tags: apache-flink, datadog, pyflink

In Flink, I am generating custom metrics in a FlatMapFunction using Python.

```py
class OccupancyEventFlatMap(FlatMapFunction):
    def open(self, runtime_context: RuntimeContext):
        mg = runtime_context.get_metrics_group()
        self.counter_sum = mg.counter("my_counter_sum")
        self.counter_total = mg.counter("my_counter_total")
    def flat_map(self, value):
        self.counter_sum.inc(10)
        self.counter_total.inc()
```

I am able to query the metric using the REST API
http://localhost:43491/jobs/9a376e28a1bb022b45c127d75fb1b447/vertices/5239a5f0e3e9cdca6a88500e58b5759e/metrics?get=0.FlatMap.my_counter_sum

```json
[{"id":"0.FlatMap.my_counter_sum","value":"28201"}]
```

But I don't see any of my custom metrics in Datadog, however I see all the standard Flink metrics there.

This is my configuration in Flink for Datadog exporter

```
# Datadog
metrics.reporter.dghttp.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.datadog.DatadogHttpReporter
metrics.reporter.dghttp.dataCenter: US
metrics.reporter.dghttp.apikey: ${datadog_api_key}
metrics.reporter.dghttp.tags: env:development

# https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/flink/#configuration
metrics.scope.jm: flink.jobmanager
metrics.scope.jm.job: flink.jobmanager.job
metrics.scope.tm: flink.taskmanager
metrics.scope.tm.job: flink.taskmanager.job
metrics.scope.task: flink.task
metrics.scope.operator: flink.operator
```

It's the first time I am tying to send custom metrics from Flink to Datadog.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was using the configuration from Flink 1.15 documentation but using it on Flink 1.16

It's working now. These are the changes needed.

```
+    metrics.reporters: prom,dghttp
+
     # Prometheus
-    metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
+    metrics.reporter.prom.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporterFactory
     metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9249
 
     # Datadog
-    metrics.reporter.dghttp.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.datadog.DatadogHttpReporter
+    metrics.reporter.dghttp.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.datadog.DatadogHttpReporterFactory
```